# Notepad++ searches the last word I clicked on

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, search, text-editors

When I press into the Notepad++ window (which means clicking on some word) and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, this defaults the search window to searching the word I clicked. I do not want this to happen, I would rather have it default to the last thing I searched.

This would make sense if I were pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> while I had something *highlighted*, but merely having the blinking writing indicator thing in the middle of a word is enough to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> default to that word. Any way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open *Settings > Preferences > Searching* and check *"Don't fill find field in Find dialog with selected word"*

[image: Searching options]